# If my 20 apps use the same framework, but with different content (story) in each, will it violate any Apple Store rules?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have a framework to create interactive stories.

I want to distribute my 20 stories as 20 independent apps.

I heard some rumors saying that Apple will reject Apps with very similar codes. I have all the same codes, just with different content in it. Since my framework is a bit heavy, the package would contain much more code than content.

Is that a "NO" for apple store?

Comment: Unfortunately, only Apple can say what they will and won't approve.  Apple tends to reject Apps from the same developer that are functionally similar, but have slightly different appearance ("Flappy bird","Flappy bat","Flappy Cat"....).  Simply having the same framework inside the app may not be an issue.  You could consider releasing a single app with the different stories unlocked by IAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple won't like a bunch of similar apps from one developer.

We submitted 15 or so learning apps with same base coding, but with different content. Some were similar subjects, which Apple eventually required to be in a single app. Combining very different content into a single app might be problematic for marketing reasons.  I think you could get away with say 5 different apps, but 20?... I say very unlikely.